# Read Flask Session Cookie

Tags: python, session, cookies

I currently have the following:

```
from flask import Flask, session,request

@app.route('/venue/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def venue_login():
    token = generate_token()
    session['venue_id'] = token
    return json.dumps(...)
```

When I look at the `response` in `Chrome`, I can see that `Set-Cookie:session=...` has been set.

I have 2 questions:

**1)** How do I read this `cookie` on the `server?

I have tried:

```
venue_id = request.cookies.get('venue_id')
```

but this doesn't seem to be picking it up.

**2)** With my code above, all my `cookies` will be set with the same name. After reading the `cookie` value, I would like to `delete` the corresponding entry in `session`. How should I go about doing this? Also if two `requests` come in one after the other, will the line:

```
session['venue_id'] = token
```

override the first entry with the second? Or does every `request` start a new `session`?

I am kind of confused with how this all should work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. Cookies and sessions are a bit different.

If you want to use cookies and make `venue_id = request.cookies.get('venue_id')` work - You need to use `set_cookie`:
`set_cookie('venue_id', token)`
In cookies case - you can solve general problems that cookies can solve (have a long lasting cookie for example)

If you want to use session (which is intended for session uniqueness and auth) you need to just use session and put the "username" or the unique ID of the venue in your case.

Which to use - It really depends what you are trying to achieve

Have a look at:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#cookies
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#sessions

Comment: Thanks @Boaz. If I used a unique `id`, how would I know what to check for in the `session`. In the docs they have this example `if 'username' in session:`: however I wouldn't know what to search for if it was `unique`?Sorry if I am not completely understanding the way this works.

Comment: OK. Lets make order in things: The user (venue?) calls login. It provides credentials of some sort. Also if not. You should have a piece of code that says: "Yeah OK, that's venue X".
When you know it is venue X - just do `session['venue_id']=<X's unique ID>` and that's it

Comment: Yes thanks @Boaz. This is what I have done in my app. The reason for all this was because I am using `Flask SocketIO` and when an initial connection is made, I wanted to ensure that not just anyone was allowed to make a connection. I want to achieve this by looking to see whether the `cookie` I had set earlier is present at the time of making the connection. How can I achieve this second step? Thanks for your help.

Comment: option 1 - check for this token on each endpoint function you make.
option 2 - if that is what you are trying to do - take a look at https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/ which is probably the right way for you to do it...

Comment: Yep, I have been using the `itsdangerous` library to generate my `tokens`. You mentioned that `venue_id = request.cookies.get('venue_id')` wasn't the correct code to use if I am using `sessions`. What would be the correct way to extract the `token` I set previously? I have tried `s = requests.Session() if s.cookies:` but it never returned anything.. Thanks.

Comment: There is no problem using get, you just need to set it with: `set_cookie('venue_id', token)` are you still getting nothing?